Fluxor with WPF
I have a legacy WPF application that's been converted to .NET 8.  Everything works great, except the singletons we have in the app, which will not transfer easily to a Blazor Server App.  I was able to spin up a Blazor App with the preexisting libraries and utilize Fluxor to manage state. And this works great.
However, in the WPF app, I am unable to get Fluxor to inject things like IState.  It is always null in constructors.  Both the Blazor Server & WPF apps need to use the same Fluxor State management now.
In my WPF App.xaml.cs:
var coll = new ServiceCollection();

coll.AddFluxor(o => o.ScanAssemblies(typeof(ModelState).Assembly));

var store = (IStore)ServiceCollectionExtension.Resolve(coll, typeof(Store));            
store.InitializeAsync().Wait();

coll.AddScoped<IPricingService, PricingService>();


public class PricingService : IPricingService
{
public PricingService(IDispatcher dispatcher, IState<PricingState> pricingState...
     _dispatcher = dispatcher;
     _pricingState = pricingState;

pricingState is always null, since I cannot register my IState with the normal Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection
Note, the IDispatcher seems to inject fine.

I believe the issue is that I cannot register the Fluxor.Web.Blazor.StoreInitializer, becuase all I have is the WPF application and no razor component.
I might try this and add the StoreInitilizer there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-8.0

By following this,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-8.0
You can then embed the Fluxor.Web.Blazor.StoreInitializer in a razor component within WPF.

Please see section Provide context for links in How to write a good answer.

Yea, so this did not work.  I understand now that Session State is not a universal cross-platform concept. :(  Although, it should be.
